# JqueryUi Range slider: put min and max values into separated fields

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, range

Currently the range slider outputs min&max values into single text field. I think that's wrong behavior, at least for me :)

Is there a way to separate these values using two different "input" fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the demo code at http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range you can see that the maximum and minimum values are avaliable from

**Min**

```
$("#slider-range").slider("values", 0)
```

**Max**

```
$("#slider-range").slider("values", 1)
```

or from within the slider callback with

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
            ui.values[0]/*min*/;
                            ui.values[1]/*max*/;
        }
```